# Play a sound file by specifying its name

Tags: android

I am trying to play a sound file in Android by getting the filename from the user. How do I find and play the sound file located in the Raw folder using its name?

I know that the process of doing this is the same as fetching a Bitmap using its name by running the code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(con.getResources(),con.getResources().getIdentifier(name_of_file, "drawable", con.getPackageName()));`
```

But I don't know how to do it on sound files.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
public static int getResId(String drawableName) {    
    try {
        Class res = R.drawable.class;
        Field field = res.getField(drawableName);
        int drawableId = field.getInt(null);
        System.out.println("resource ids****"+drawableId);
        return drawableId;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MyTag", "Failure to get drawable id.", e);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I am using this in this way:

```
ImageView my_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_imageView);
my_image.setBackgroundResource(getResId("ic_launcher"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get the id of the ressource and then start the Mediaplayer with that id

Something like that

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(name,folder,packagename);
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, resId);
mp.start();
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: `android.content.res.ResourcesNotFoundException: File res/raw/ako1.3ga from drawable resource ID #0x7f040000`. I am sure that this file is existing inside res/raw folder

Comment: what parameters did you use, exactly? maybe the package name is wrong, or you were naming 'folder' "/res/raw" instead of "raw". Hard to find your problem without such information